# Calling Firebird Stored procedure from Java Servlet

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I have a Firebird Database with some stored procedure, and I am developing a Java web/database application. I want to know if it is possible and how to call those stored procedures from a java Class or a Servlet.

example:

1. Stored procedure `deletep`, used to delete a row from database
2. my webapp Jsp/servlets
3. I want to create a link that execute my delete stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a Firebird stored procedure in Java, there are several ways. The JDBC-default method would be something like:

```
try (CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "{call yourProcedure(?, ?, ?)}")) {
    cstmt.setString(1, "value1");
    cstmt.setString(2, "value2");
    cstmt.setString(3, "value3");
    cstmt.execute();
}
```

If the Firebird stored procedure was selectable (that is: contains `SUSPEND` and can return multiple rows), you would need to do something like:

```
try (CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "{call yourProcedure(?, ?, ?)}")) {
    cstmt.setString(1, "value1");
    cstmt.setString(2, "value2");
    cstmt.setString(3, "value3");
    try (ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery()) {
        while(rs.next()) {
            // do something with result set rows ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is sufficient if the stored procedure is executable and doesn't return any values. If the stored procedure is executable with (multiple) return columns, you'd need to something like:

```
try (CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "{call yourProcedure(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}")) {
    cstmt.setString(1, "value1");
    cstmt.setString(2, "value2");
    cstmt.setString(3, "value3");
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR)
    cstmt.execute();

    String out1 = cstmt.getString(4);
    String out2 = cstmt.getString(5);
    // do something with result
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the Firebird specific syntax `EXECUTE PROCEDURE yourProcedure(?, ?, ?)` for executable stored procedures and `SELECT * FROM yourProcedure(?, ?, ?)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using Jaybird, the Firebird JDBC driver.

Three steps:

1. Create a DBUtil java class to stock the query :

   ```
   public static void deletePlan(Connection conn, CallableStatement 
           statement, String code, String rev, String mention) throws SQLException {  

       statement.setString(1, code);
       statement.setString(2, rev);
       statement.setString(3, mention);
       statement.execute();
   }
   ```
2. Create the delete servlet

   ```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
           HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       Connection conn = MyUtils.getStoredConnection(request);

       String code = request.getParameter("code");
       String rev = request.getParameter("revision");
       String mention = request.getParameter("mention");
       CallableStatement statement = null;
       try {
           statement = conn.prepareCall("execute procedure 
       DELETEP(?,?,?)");
       } catch (SQLException e1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e1.printStackTrace();
       }

       String errorString = null;

       try {
           DBUtils.deletePlan(conn, statement, code, rev, mention);
       } catch (SQLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           errorString = e.getMessage();
       } 
       .........
   ```
3. Create the delete link in the jsp file

   ```
   <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deletePlan code=${plan.code}&revision=${plan.revision}&mention=${plan.mention}">Delete</a>
   ```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't create that `DBUtile` class, it is an odd abstraction. Read up on DAOs, and move all database related code out of the servlet. I'd also suggest that in step 2 that you coalesce your try-catch blocks into one block, the second block shouldn't (and can't) be executed if the first failed. Also read up on try-with-resources. Using a `GET` for a delete is odd and potentially unsafe (all you need is a search engine crawling your page or a browser prefetching links for thinks to get deleted). You really should use POST for deletes.